# Test Queries in Rails with MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Method trying to test:

```
def self.by_date(date)
  where("DATE(created_at) = ?", date)
end
```

Comments.yml (fixture):

```
one:
  user_id: 1
  job_id: 24
  content: "This is a test"
```

Current Test:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'date'

class CommentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

setup do
  @comment = comments(:one)
end

test 'organizes by date' do
  @comment.created_at = Date.today
  assert_equal @comment.created_at, Comment.by_date(Date.today).first.created_at
end

end
```

I end up with:

```
2) Failure:
  CommentTest#test_organizes_by_date 
  --- expected
  +++ actual
  @@ -1 +1 @@
 -Fri, 22 Apr 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
 +Fri, 22 Apr 2016 20:48:42 UTC +00:00
```

I am assuming there is a way more efficent way to test this but have found no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@comment.created_at` is a `Date`, but `Comment.by_date(Date.today).first.created_at` is a `DateTime` object.

Try to convert your `DateTime` object to `Date`:

```
assert_equal @comment.created_at, Comment.by_date(Date.today).first.created_at.to_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to test that the correct comments are returned by the self.by_date method. Does the precise time matter or can it just be within the same day or same hour?

Create another comment and set its created date to yesterday. Then test that the result includes the comment created today and not the comment created yesterday.

```
class CommentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  setup do
    @comment1 = comments(:one)
    @comment2 = comments(:one)
  end

  test 'organizes by date' do
    @comment1.created_at = Time.now
    @comment2.created_at = Time.now - 1.day
    assert_equal [@comment1], Comment.by_date(Time.now)
    assert_equal [@comment2], Comment.by_date(Time.now - 1.day)
  end

end
```

You'll need to do some additional date manipulation in the method to get comments for the day as opposed to the precise time.

```
def self.by_date
  where(created_at: Time.now.day)
end
```

If you want the precise time of creation, maybe look at using [TimeCop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) which is helpful for testing on precise timings.

Apologies in advance for minitest syntax errors, I generally use rspec.